# EditText constantly returns Empty - Android

Tags: java, android, null, android-edittext

I'm attempting to null check an EditText (which should be simple enough) however each time I enter text into my two ET's - they always return as empty: "" and they should not (if they have text in them).

I've looked over several other SO articles related to this and none of the fixes seem to resolve the issue.

Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong in this instance?

### Source Snippet:

Java class:

...

```
public void doneClicked(View v) throws JSONException {

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v1 = li.inflate(R.layout.profile_notification_settings_list_edit, null);

    final EditText label = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.emaillabel);
    final EditText value = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.emailvalue);

    String sValue = value.getText().toString();
    if (sValue.matches("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    String sLabel = label.getText().toString();
    if (sLabel.matches("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a label", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```

...

Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_notification_settings_list_edit, null);
    EditText value = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.emailvalue);
    value.setHint("Value");
    value.setText(valueList[i]);

    EditText label = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.emaillabel);
    if (labelList != null)
        label.setHint("Label");
    label.setText(labelList[i]);
```

### Full source:

Java Class:

https://pastebin.com/y1e9J1yE

Adapter:

https://pastebin.com/Zqh3eCAk

Answer (score 3):

Because everytime you click you are creating a new `view` which has nothing to do with the views currently being displayed on the screen

```
public void doneClicked(View v) throws JSONException {

    // don't inflate new views
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v1 = li.inflate(R.layout.profile_notification_settings_list_edit, null);

    final EditText label = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.emaillabel);
    final EditText value = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.emailvalue);

    // ... code
```

**Note** : you cannot directly fetch the data from `rowItemVies` from `ListView` , so you need to add method in your adapter class to get the selected position through which you can fetch the `rowView` using `yourListView.getChildAt(position)` and further fetch data from children in `rowView`

Comment: You're fast! One note though, you should have a reference to your `TextEdit` items in the controller class, there is no need to use `view.findViewById(..)` all the time.

Comment: @xander thanks and  you are right and OP should use `view` for optimization though The code is saying a lot with issues

Comment: ...is there any way you might be able to show or point to an example of how that might be accomplished? (getting the selected position)

Comment: @AndroidAndroidAndroid if you want to get the value of one selected row then you can implement `setOnItemClickListener` to get the position and store it to a global variable in cliass then later do `View rowView = mListView.getChildAt(position)` so now you can do `EditText label = (EditText) rowView .findViewById(R.id.emaillabel);` and so on

Comment: **Note** :your adapter has empty code for `getItemId` and so on , you should track all issues carefully and eliminate them as well

Answer (score -1):

use 
sValue.trim().equals("") instead of sValue.matches("")